# How to rewrite a space (%20) in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get some old URL's to redirect to the homepage. I tried it like below but it doesn't appear to work. Also tried some regex, but no results.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/%20article%20name(/?)$ / [R,L]
```

How is this to be done?

Comment: The path RewriteRule matches against, is already URL-decoded.

Comment: @CBroe, but if I use `^blog/ article name(/?)$` it will crash. How should it be formatted in htaccess, the decoded way?

Comment: Just use: `\s` i.e `RewriteRule ^blog/\sarticle\sname/?$ / [R,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

To be able to match whitespace in URI, you can use perl property for whitespaces `\s` in your rule like this:

```bash
RewriteRule ^blog/\sarticle\sname/?$ / [R=302,NC,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.